# ¿Cómo esperar un tiempo antes de hacer una ejecución?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente if, como ven cada vez que la variable esta en false entra y ejecuta el método enviar pagos, este if yo lo tengo dentro de un ciclo entonces se esta ejecutando constantemente

**EnviarPago** es un servicio y como se esta ejecutando constantemente  el servicio me devuelve que no se puede enviar tantas peticiones en tan poco tiempo, dentro de este if puse un   `Thread.Sleep(10000);` para así decirle antes de entrar a este método espere 10 segundos y funciona pero lo que he visto es que cada vez que entra al **Thread**  la app se bloquea esos 10 segundos

¿Como puedo dentro del if decir que por cada minuto solo se ejecute 5 veces, o espere un tiempo para que no se ejecute cada segundo?

"**Sin usar un Timer**"

```
 Inte = pagos.Integration;
                    if (Inte == false)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        var Respuesta = await proxy.EnviarPago(pagos);
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en este caso, es mejor utilizar `Task.delay(100)`, esto hace una espera, sin bloquear el hilo actual, `task.sleep(100)` no se recomienda en peticiones asincronas

```
Inte = pagos.Integration;
 if (Inte == false)
  {
   Await Task.Delay(10000);
    var Respuesta = await proxy.EnviarPago(pagos);
  }
```

puedes obtener mas informacion en esta pregunta [de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

y en la documentacion puedes encontrar varios [ejemplos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-5.0)